# How to deserialize YAML with YAMLDotNet?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I want to deserialize this YAML with YAMLDotNet.
It have sequence and nested mapping.

- data.yml

```
people:
  - name: "John"
    age: 20
  - name: "Michael"
    age: 21
  - name: "William"
    age: 22

network:
  address: "192.168.1.1"
  port: 1234
  param:
    paramNumber: 10
    paramString: "text data"
    paramBool: true
```

This is my code. But, It can't compile.
I would like to know the following two things.

1. How to define class to decerialize nested mapping?
2. How to access it?

- Print Deserialized Data

```cs
DeserializedObject obj = YamlImporter.Deserialize("data.yml");

foreach(var people in obj.people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(people.name);
    Console.WriteLine(people.age);
}

Console.WriteLine(obj.network["address"]);
Console.WriteLine(obj.network["port"]);
/* how to access param? */
```

- Deserializer Code (YAMLDotNet)

```cs
public class YamlImporter
{
    public static DeserializedObject Deserialize(string yamlName)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(yamlName);
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var input = new StringReader(text);
        var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder().WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance).Build();
        DeserializedObject deserializeObject = deserializer.Deserialize<DeserializedObject>(input); /* compile error */
        return deserializeObject;
    }
}

public class DeserializedObject
{
    public List<People> people { get; set; }

    public class People
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Network> network { get; set; }

    public class Network
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int port { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Param> param { get; set; }
    }

    public class Param
    {
        public int paramNumber { get; set; }
        public string paramString { get; set; }
        public bool paramBool { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: `Network.port` is an `int`. You cannot index into an `int`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh, it was a small mistake. Thanks!    
`obj.port["port"]` -> `obj.network["port"]`

Comment: However, my problem still remains.

Comment: Well for one thing, `param` is misspelled. The value is named `params` in the YAML. `params` is a keyword in C#. You can use it as a property name by prefixing it with `@`: `@params { get; set; }`. I don't know how you expected it to work with the wrong name though.

Comment: You also have dictionaries that don't make sense. `@params` should be of type `Params`, `network` should be of type `Network`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks, I will change from `params` to `param` in YAML. I think it can avoid the keywords.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I finally understood your advice.
I will remove Dictionary of network and param. It was unnecessary.
It solved everything my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you got everything worked out but it is a bad practice to change your data because of a keyword present in an unrelated language. I would have stuck with `@params`. The reason you can prefix reserved words in C# is to handle interop with other languages which is precisely what this is. Furthermore, since you are using the `CamelCaseNamingConvention`, you can PascalCase all of your C# properties, allowing your code to conform to language conventions, another interop feature, in this case provided by the YAMLDotNet library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AluanHaddad's advice helped me solve my problem. Thanks,

```cs
// How to access params? //
Console.WriteLine(obj.network.param.paramNumber);
Console.WriteLine(obj.network.param.paramString);
Console.WriteLine(obj.network.param.paramBool);
```

```cs
//public Dictionary<string, Network> network { get; set; }
public Network network { get; set; }

public class Network
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public int port { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<string, Param> param { get; set; }
    public Param param { get; set; }
}
```